# Transfer XML file with a languages section to a database table using XSLT

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, xslt, xslt-2.0

below is a part of the xml file I get. I want to transfer this to a single mssql database table. My problem are the different languages of each job-element. The three languages below won't change in time.

I want to create 2 columns for each language in the db-table.

Example: **EnglishTitle** & **EnglishDescription**

```
 <jobs>
        <job nr="1">
          <language name="English">
            <title>English title</title>
            <description>
              <li>English description</li>
              <li>English description 2</li>
              <li>English description 3</li>
            </description>
          </language>
          <language name="German">
            <title>German title</title>
            <description>German description</description>
          </language>
          <language name="Chinese">
            <title>Business Mission Chinese</title>
            <description>German description</description>
          </language>
          <general>For all languages</general>
        </job>
</jobs>
```

How can I use XSLT to lookup the language name attribute and create two elements for each language with the content of the name attribute?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I think the output should look like:

```
 <jobs>
        <job nr="1">
            <EnglishTitle>English title</EnglishTitle>
            <EnglishDescription>
              <li>English description</li>
              <li>English description 2</li>
              <li>English description 3</li>
            </EnglishDescription>
            <GermanTitle>German title</GermanTitle>
            <GermanDescription>German description</GermanDescription>
            <ChineseTitle>Business Mission Chinese</ChineseTitle>
            <ChineseDescription>Chinese description</ChineseDescription>
          <general>For all languages</general>
        </job>
</jobs>
```

Additionally how should I store the `<li>`-Elements
of a description in the table? Should I replace them with new lines or with a special character?

If there is a better way feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should have a separate row for each individual description, with columns describing the job number (hopefully unique), the language and the description itself. So something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/jobs">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="job/language/description/text() | job/language/description/li ">
            <row>
                <col><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::job/@nr"/></col>
                <col><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::language/@name"/></col>
                <col><xsl:value-of select="."/></col>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which in your example would return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
   <row>
      <col>1</col>
      <col>English</col>
      <col>English description</col>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col>1</col>
      <col>English</col>
      <col>English description 2</col>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col>1</col>
      <col>English</col>
      <col>English description 3</col>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col>1</col>
      <col>German</col>
      <col>German description</col>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col>1</col>
      <col>Chinese</col>
      <col>German description</col>
   </row>
</table>
```

Comment: but with this solution I can't assign the columns to a specific db-table column. I've edit my initial post and added my "preferred" solution.

Comment: "*with this solution I can't assign the columns to a specific db-table column.*' Why not? -- Your "preferred" solution is not normalized. Among other flaws, it assumes that there will always be exactly the three languages named in your example.